# Is there a way to ignore "Missing return type on function" for Angular lifecycle methods?

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

We're using Angular and I'm trying to switch from tslint to eslint.
A rule that throws around 600 warnings is the `Missing return type on function`
from `eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types`.

I do understand that I should use return types for my functions and how to do it. There's virtually no use for lifecycle methods in Angular though. What should I return from `ngOnInit`?

So the question is: how can I use this rule for every function but not `ngOnInit`, `ngOnDestroy` etc?

```
ngOnInit(): void { // meh
    ...
}

ngOnInit() { // yay
    ...
}
```

Just in case that it is relevant, my .eslintrc.json:

```
extends": [
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
],
```

Comment: What the difference between your "meh" and "yay" examples? Did you mean to omit the type declaration from one of them?

Comment: @Noah You've answered your own question; the difference is the omission of the return type. The asker's question is about avoiding linting errors when omitting return types for Angular lifecycle hooks (such as OnInt).

Comment: @EdWilliams The poster made that edit in reaction to my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @Ibsn's answer I could come up with this config:

```
"rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": [
      "warn",
      {
        "allowedNames": ["ngOnInit", "ngOnDestroy", "ngAfterViewInit", "ngOnChanges"]
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but it looks like that rule accepts a `allowedNames` option where you can pass an array of method names not to be checked.

Note that this will also disable checking types on the method's arguments.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md

Answer (score 0):

There are to ways to solve this problem:

1. Add before every line with error comment like below to ignore every error in place:

```
 // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
```

2. Just globally ignore this type of errors:

```
    
    "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": ["unused-imports"],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off"
    }
```

Comment: Read the question again: "how can I use this rule for every function but not x & y". :)